# Building asp.net core project in debug mode creates no artifacts?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-1.0

When I build my asp.net core project in release mode I can find the artifacts at directory:

```
C:\TGB.App\artifacts\bin\TGB.Web\Release
```

but when I build my asp.net core project in debug mode I can not find it anywhere within/below artifacts folder.

Why is that?

Comment: Not au fait with core, are you building via a script? Are there any post build activities on the project?

Comment: au fait ? I build in release mode just in VS 2015 not more.

Comment: Ok check the post build events in the project properties for release, I think you'll see a copy command \ task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to select "produce output on build" option in your project build properties.

Comment: Stupid, why is that not by default like in web api 2 projects? ... Thanks!

Comment: Because now with Roslyn you can run from source!

Comment: Does that mean I can point my debug output to local IIS and I get real time iis update when I rebuild?

Comment: Ctrl-F5 will do just that.